# Is there a way to perform operations on groups in SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite, aggregate-functions

So I am very new to SQL and am probably not describing what I want to do accurately. I have a table with three columns and I want to group by one column and see what percentage of each group has a certain value in the other column. For example in the table:

```
id   col1  col2
----------------
0       A     1
1       A     2
2       B     2
3       B     2
4       A     1
```

I would want to group by `col1` and see what percentage of each group (`A` or `B`) has value 1 in `col2`. The result I want from this is:

```
col1  percentage_col2_equals_1
------------------------------
   A                      66.7
   B                       0.0
```

So far I have:

```
SELECT col1,
((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table
WHERE col2 = 1
GROUP BY col1) / 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table
GROUP BY col1) * 100)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY col1;
```

But this does not work. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I am using SQLite3 on Python

Answer (score 1):

use `case when`

```
SELECT col1,(coalesce(count(case when col2=1 then col2 end),0)*100.00)/count(*)
from tablename
group by col1
```

Answer (score 1):

Same answer as everyone, just putting this here due to Postgres' expressiveness :)

Live test: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/goL488VaPuZYii7Wik3pFk/4

```
select
    col1,
    count(*) filter(where col2 = 1) ::numeric / count(*)

from tbl    
group by col1;
```

Output:

```
| col1 | ?column?               |
| ---- | ---------------------- |
| A    | 0.66666666666666666667 |
| B    | 0.00000000000000000000 |
```

To present it as percentage with 1 decimal place, multiply it by 100 and round to 1:

Live test: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/goL488VaPuZYii7Wik3pFk/5

```
select
    col1,    
    round( 
      count(*) filter(where col2 = 1) ::numeric / count(*) * 100, 
      1 
    ) as p_a      
from tbl    
group by col1;


select
    col1,    
    (
        count(*) filter(where col2 = 1) ::numeric / count(*) * 100
    )::numeric(100,1) as p_b       
from tbl    
group by col1;
```

Output:

```
| col1 | p_a  |
| ---- | ---- |
| A    | 66.7 |
| B    | 0.0  |


| col1 | p_b  |
| ---- | ---- |
| A    | 66.7 |
| B    | 0.0  |
```

Comment: The `filter (...)` syntax is actually part of the SQL standard, it's not Postgres specific. There are however only very few DBMS that actually implement this (to my knowledge the only others are HSQLDB and SQLite)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Nice to know that it's SQL standard. Postgres is the most SQL standard-compliant database, and it's always in the lead when there's a new functionality in SQL standard, which sometimes gives me the impression that a functionality is specific to Postgres :D

Answer (score 0):

The following query will return your expected result:

```
SELECT col1, 
       CAST(((SUM(IIF(col2 = 1, 1, 0))) * 100.0) / COUNT(*) AS DECIMAL(5, 1)) AS percentage_col2_equals_1
FROM my_table
GROUP BY col1;
```

Sample execution with sample data:

```
DECLARE @my_table TABLE (id INT,  col1 CHAR(1),  col2 INT);

INSERT INTO @my_table (id, col1, col2) VALUES
(0, 'A', 1),
(1, 'A', 2),
(2, 'B', 2),
(3, 'B', 2),
(4, 'A', 1);

SELECT col1, CAST(((SUM(IIF(col2 = 1, 1, 0))) * 100.0) / COUNT(*) AS DECIMAL(5, 1)) AS percentage_col2_equals_1
FROM @my_table
GROUP BY col1;
```

Output:

```
col1    percentage_col2_equals_1
---------------------------------
A       66.7
B       0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     CREATE TABLE #TEMP
    (ID   INT, 
     COL1 VARCHAR(10), 
     COL2 INT
    );
    INSERT INTO #TEMP
           SELECT 0, 'A',1
           UNION
           SELECT 1, 'A',2
           UNION
           SELECT 2, 'B',2
           UNION
           SELECT 3, 'B',2
           UNION
           SELECT 4, 'A',1;
    SELECT T.COL1, 
           ROUND((CAST(COUNT(CASE
                                 WHEN T.COL2 = 1
                                 THEN T.COL2
                                 ELSE NULL
                             END) AS DECIMAL) / (S.COL2)) * 100.0, 2) AS Percentage_1
    FROM #TEMP T
         JOIN
    (
        SELECT COUNT(COL2) COL2, 
               COL1
        FROM #TEMP
        GROUP BY COL1
    ) S ON S.COL1 = T.COL1
    GROUP BY T.COL1, 
             S.COL2;
```

Comment: You can use a fiddle to avoid repeating the data in your answer. Here's a good one: https://www.db-fiddle.com/ No need to type the DDL and creation of data manually, just click the Text to DDL, then paste the OP's textual data. It will generate the DDL and creation of data for you

Comment: Thanks I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ("id" int, "col1" varchar2(1), "col2" int)
;
//do inserts
select aa."col1",((select count(*) from Table1 b 
where b."col1"=aa."col1" and b."col2"=1 )*100/(select count(*) 
from Table1 c where c."col1"='A' )) percentge
from Table1 aa
group by aa."col1"
;
```

output:

```
A   66.66666666666666666666666666666666666667
B   0
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQLite the expression `col2 = 1` returns `1` when `true` and `0` when `false`.
So you just need the average of `col2 = 1` and then round it to 1 decimal:

```
select
  col1,
  round(100.0 * avg(col2 = 1), 1) percentage_col2_equals_1
from tablename  
group by col1
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/syiViySSi8dh9sYLoZKjjU/1).
Results:

```
| col1 | percentage_col2_equals_1 |
| ---- | ------------------------ |
| A    | 66.7                     |
| B    | 0                        |
```